# Game with bitmaps randomly appearing from the right

Tags: java, android, eclipse, random, bitmap

So I am trying to make a Game in which there is a square that goes up and down and then there is red squares that appear from the right hand side and slide left. So far I have only managed to make one red Square appear randomly and slide to the left but I can't seem to make others. What I am trying to do is set something like a timer so that every second or so a new red square will appear randomly. When I run the game all that happens is a see the square and there is one red square going from right to left. Please tell me what I can add in order to make more red squares appear. Please help.

The code:

```
public class Game extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

GameView gameView;
Bitmap square;
Bitmap redSquare;
float x, y;
Random random;
float redSquareY, redSquareX;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    gameView = new GameView(this);
    gameView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    square = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.square);
    redSquare = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.redsquare);
    x = y = 200;
    setContentView(gameView);
    redSquare = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.redsquare);
    random = new Random();
    redSquareX = 500;
    redSquareY = random.nextInt(400);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    gameView.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    gameView.resume();
}

public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

    Thread thread = null;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    boolean running = false;
    Canvas canvas;

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    holder = getHolder();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(running == true){ 
            if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()){
                continue;
            } 

            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawRGB(100, 100, 100);
            canvas.drawBitmap(square, x - (square.getWidth()/2), y - (square.getHeight()/2), null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(redSquare, redSquareX, redSquareY, null);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            y = y + 4;
            redSquareX = redSquareX - 1;

        }

        }

    public void pause(){
        running = false;
        while(true){
            try{
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } break;
        } thread = null;
    }

    public void resume(){
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

 }

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    switch(event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        y = y - 100;
        break;

    }

    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am slightly confused on your setup, but I'll give it a shot.

```
if(System.nanoTime() - lastSquareTime > 1500000000) { 
    startRedSquares();  
}
```

This piece of code shouldn't be in onCreate. onCreate is only called once and so it's never going to start creating more red squares with this if-statement. You should be checking that timer in the run method, which is game loop. So, more like this:

```
while(running == true){ 
            if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()){
                continue;
            } 

            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawRGB(100, 100, 100);
            canvas.drawBitmap(square, x - (square.getWidth()/2), y - (square.getHeight()/2), null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(redSquare, redSquareX, redSquareY, null);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            y = y + 4;

            if(SOME TIMER HAS EXPIRED) {
                //add another red square to the list
                //reset timer 
            }
            //DECREMENT THE TIMER 
            //CHECK IF ANY SQUARE IS OFF THE SCREEN AND REMOVE IT FROM LIST
            //LOOP THROUGH LIST AND MOVE ALL REDSQUARES

            redSquareX = redSquareX - 1;

}
```

Alternatively I would also recommend making a class for your redsquares and then making and ArrayList of RedSquare objects. Then as you loop through each RedSquare object can call their own methods (updateMovement, checkIfOffScreen, drawRedSquare) or whatever you want to call them.